# Add external Jar file to Play 2.0.4

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

Because Play Framework does not support Cassandra and to avoid build problems with Play project thus I made a Java project (Based on Kundaru's work) and named it KConnector, in the KConnector project, there are some external libraries (Kundaru's jar files) thus I exported the project as a runnable Jar file (If I exported to Jar file only, it wouldn't pack external libs). Then by following [Instruction](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.4/SBTDependencies), I create a Playproject/lib folder then put a built jar file inside that. The problem is I cannot call classes inside the KConnector jar file....
Eclipse could not recognize what they are and it suggested me some imports, but none of them is mine...Can anybody please show mw where I were wrong?

P/S: I also tried running play ec or play compile but there was no hope... Even I ran play ec, the file in lib also disappeared to Eclipse...

Thank you very much.

Comment: Try running the eclipsy command again once the files are in the dir

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I use play 2.0.4 and I use an external jar, I created a lib folder inside the project, added the jar in this folder, run 'eclipsify' command and refresh the project in eclipse and I don't have problem.

Comment: is your `lib` at the same level as `app`, `conf`, and `tests`?

Comment: Yes, the lib folder has same level as app, conf and tests. I just try, it works ^^

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the project and select "Configure Build Path..."
Under libraries click "Add external jar"
Select your jar in the file system and you should be all set