# Using external jars in Play framework

Tags: playframework-2.0

Recently, I tried to use java-image-scaling library to resize the image files. So, I set java-image-scaling jar file through Eclipse as a way that usual Eclipse project sets its external jar file. In Eclipse, there is no error (I mean, there is no red underline.) to use java-image-scaling library. However, when I try to compile it through Play! console, the compiler said it cannot find java-image-scaling jar file. It is weird because I did exactly same with Joda Time library and there was no problem.

Am I missing something to use external jar(java library) in a project of Play framework?

[image]

Check this screenshot that shows I already added Joda datatime library and java-image-scaling library.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have to add your dependency in the `project/Build.scala` file:

```
val appDependencies = Seq(
  "com.mortennobel" % "java-image-scaling" % "0.8.5"
)
```

Or you can drop your jar directly in a `lib` folder of your Play app.

Then, in the Play console, regenerate the Eclipse files using the command `eclipsify` or `eclipse` according to your Play version (2.1.x or 2.0.x).

For Joda time, it worked because this library is already existing in the Play dependencies.

Please refer to the [Play documentation](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.4/SBTDependencies) for further details.

Answer (score 2):

Here you find the procedure to add external jar in your project if you don't want to use dependencies: [Add external Jar file to Play 2.0.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12820715/add-external-jar-file-to-play-2-0-4/12822926#12822926)

Answer (score 0):

in play 1.x, you can add include in `conf/dependencies.yml`